# Automatically associate clients to pods

Tags: database, testing, kubernetes, cluster-computing, replication

Is it possible to have a client always connect to the same database in a cluster? I mean: I would like to have a pool of databases (all with the same image but data-wise independent between them). Then, I would like to expose an IP and port at the cluster. When a client connects to this address, I would like the Kubernetes to automatically associate this cliente with a brand new database inside the cluster. This database should never be associated to any other client. All the times the given client conencts to the IP and port at the cluster, it should connect to the same database.

In case a new client accesses the service and now fresh databases are available, I would like k8s to automatically create a new database and associate it to the client.

Is this possible or pure fantasy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is related to your other question on [Exlusive client affinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631684/exlusive-client-affinity) . You could create databases that are exposed exclusively for particular clients. But you would need to write code to create them dynamically e.g. using the Kubernetes APIs. I can't see any Kubernetes feature to do the on-demand provisioning part. Kubernetes can automatically scale up a deployment in Kubernetes but that is quite different from automatically creating whole new deployments.

Comment: I understand the API can be used to send commands like create Pod, list Deployments... How could I use the API so as to automatically create a pod when an IP:port is accessed?

Comment: I think you'd want a Pod that you define that acts as an entry point and forwards to the appropriate service or creates on as necessary by using the API

Comment: I think that would work. Could you give me a hint on how to do it. The idea is to connect from clients using the psql command. Therefore, PostgreSQL proxy needs to be established at the entrypoint pod. Do you know of a proxy of that kind? I couldn't find one.

Comment: Yeah tricky. I guess you'd need to build on top of or extend something like http://ha-jdbc.org/source-repository.html If you didn't need the creation to be seamless then you could make it much easier by having a preliminary http request where the client says 'tell me which database I can use'. Then if you need to create one you can do so and reply with the address for reaching the appropriate Ingress/Service dedicated to that client.